# how should I: manage 2 living branch of a project

Tags: mercurial

I have a web project managed with Mercurial.

the  "default" Branch is the main. we use it in my company as release branch.

now I need to «clone» this release to add custom forms for a new consumer: i created a new branch: "idea"

when i find a bug in default, I just need to merge "default" into "idea" and the fix is available for the fork.

but when I fix a bug in "idea" in a release, how do i apply it into default without adding the custom forms in the default branche?

in this case, i need to merge the rev 110 and 111 in default, but only thes rev

```
o  111[tip]   3d14d9c9096d   2013-03-14 18:11 +0100   darius
|    ajout de la gestion des droit sur etat de tickets
|
o  110   5be5e130241c   2013-03-14 16:49 +0100   darius
|    correction bug unité article
|
o    109:100,108   8c2ea9d76a2f   2013-03-14 16:44 +0100   darius
|\     fusion avec default
| |
| @  108   7d175b11327f   2013-03-14 16:36 +0100   darius
| |    correction du bug des unité
| |
| o  107   adc0dcf2bfc8   2013-03-14 14:59 +0100   darius
| |    correction taille bar
| |
| o  106   f41472a6c515   2013-03-14 14:44 +0100   darius
| |    correction js des popup de fichiers attaché
| |
| o  105   e5c7e243bcca   2013-03-13 17:15 +0100   darius
| |    correction bug de blocnote et z-index typeahead
| |
| o  104   72566ddba6b3   2013-03-08 12:28 +0100   darius
| |    ajout des graphes d'activité par client
| |
| o  103   d069dfb24006   2013-03-08 10:09 +0100   darius
| |    correction du bug de blocnote supprimé a cause de char null dans le blocnote
| |
| o  102   6dc51702fde0   2013-03-07 18:06 +0100   darius
| |    ajout du lien de fichier qui ouvre dans une autre fenetre
| |
| o  101:99   96f6af3df7f7   2013-03-07 17:12 +0100   darius
| |    refractoring des stats dans une appli ticket_stats et ajout du activite by clien
| |
o |  100:97,99   941134915ff0   2013-03-06 15:34 +0100   darius
|\|    Fusion avec default
| |
| o  99   67a2e2f2b263   2013-03-06 15:11 +0100   darius
| |    correction click sur adress mail dans les ticket
| |
| o  98:95   a20ba888c900   2013-03-06 12:26 +0100   darius
| |    correction du bug des accents dans les nom de fichiers et de la modif d'activite
| |
o |  97   b1930e15c1be   2013-03-05 17:59 +0100   darius
| |    modif du settings.dev_on_prod et du formulaire de ticket
| |
o |  96:92,95   a51f00d107d7   2013-03-05 17:55 +0100   darius
|\|    Fusion avec default
| |
| o  95   f3f3234f38e6   2013-03-05 17:54 +0100   darius
| |    ajout des user pas admin ok
| |
| o  94   2c0e09aab0ab   2013-03-05 17:43 +0100   darius
| |    correction bug de creation d'utilisateur via admin
| |
| o  93:91   051d00064aba   2013-03-05 17:38 +0100   darius
| |    retrait du cache sur les ticket a cause de boucles recursive au niveau du cache
| |
o |  92:89,91   0d7ce90cd324   2013-03-05 17:08 +0100   darius
|\|    Fusion avec default
| |
| o  91   43357d05bdd6   2013-03-05 17:07 +0100   darius
| |    correction cas ou pas de hierarchie
| |
| o  90:88   984da3636ded   2013-03-05 16:12 +0100   darius
| |    correcion bug creation contacts
| |
o |  89   605374295adc   2013-03-05 15:14 +0100   darius
|/     ajout de la branche idea
|
o  88   2f699fca00d5   2013-03-05 15:12 +0100   darius
|    mise a jour des libs required
|
o  87   f37e580921cc   2013-03-05 14:32 +0100   darius
|    ajout du cache sur les objet Cegid
|
```

sry for my poor english. it is not my mother language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a work for graft.

```
hg -v help graft

This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes from
other branches without merging branches in the history graph. This is
sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'.
...
```

In your case you need a: `hg graft "110::111"`

EDIT: It looks like you're already on 108, otherwise> `hg update 108`

Answer (score 2):

It would be preferable to commit the fixes in the default branch only. If a fix is already committed in the "idea" branch, then the best thing to do is to export the fix changeset as a patch, and to apply this patch on the default branch.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the transplant extension can help with the export / import process.